# How to check the authenticity of a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

#### The Context:

- You have a web server which has to provide an exclusive content only if your client has your specific Chrome extension installed.
- You have two possibilities to provide the Chrome extension package:

  1. From the Chrome Web Store
  2. From your own server

#### The problem:

- There is a plethora of solutions allowing to know that a Chrome extension is installed:

  1. Inserting an element when a web page is loaded by using [Content Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).
  2. Sending specific headers to the server by using [Web Requests](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html).
  3. Etc.
- But there seems to be no solution to check if the Chrome extension which is interacting with your web page is genuine.
- Indeed, as the source code of the Chrome extension can be viewed and copied by anyone who want to, **there seems to be no way to know if the current Chrome extension interacting with your web page is the one you have published** or a cloned version (and maybe somewhat altered) by another person.
- It seems that you are only able to know that some Chrome extension is interacting with your web page in an "expected way" but you cannot verify its authenticity.

#### The solution?

- One solution may consist in using information contained in the Chrome extension package and which cannot be altered or copied by anyone else:

  1. Sending the Chrome extension's ID to the server? But how?

     - The ID has to be sent by you and your JavaScript code and there seems to be no way to do it with an "internal" Chrome function.
     - So if someone else just send the same ID to your server (some kind of Chrome extension's ID spoofing) then your server will consider his Chrome extension as a genuine one!
  2. Using the private key which served when you packaged the application? But how?

     - There seems to be no way to access or use in any way this key programmatically!
- One other solution my consist in using [NPAPI Plugins](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) and embed authentication methods like GPG, etc. But this solution is not desirable mostly because of the big "Warning" section of its [API's doc](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html).
- ***Is there any other solution?***

#### Notes

This question attempts to raise a real security problem in the Chrome extension's API: How to check the authenticity of your Chrome extension when it comes to interact with your services.
If there are any missing possibilities, or any misunderstandings please feel free to ask me in comments.

Comment: What is your definition of "genuine"? I understand that if someone builds a clone of your extension that obviously wouldn't be a genuine extension, but what if someone just copies the extension files from one computer to another? Do you consider the exact duplicate a "genuine" extension? I suppose the ambiguity lies in the phrase "`one you have published or a copied one by another person`" -- do you mean an exact duplicate (i.e. filesystem-copy) or a software clone?

Comment: @apsillers if the extension has been cloned it is considered as not to be genuine. But if it is copied from one computer to another as long as the extension's ID remains the same, it is still genuine because anything has be altered.

Comment: @apsillers thank you for your remark, I merged it in the new version of the question ;)

Comment: I'm afraid that an NPAPI plugin can be also compromised (even though its reverse-engineering is a bit harder than a pure extension's). If you think it's acceptable otherwise, then the warning about the "big hammer" should not stop you, because it's well justified to use a "big hammer" for the sake of security, imho. For completness of "other solutions", you should possibly mention Native Clients. The only really secured solution is to move all important code to your server. Extensions are not suited for such things at the moment.

Comment: In fact all important code is already in the server. The problem is that the client has to have the extension to access the content served by the server and as long as the extension is "copiable" anyone else can propose the same service with its own extension and server the content from my server. It's like you need a "key" to enter a room but anyone else can copy this key!

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind for this case is "client" authentication. Either require users to provide some credentials to work through the extension, or generate unique id for every instance of your extension (while downloading the extension, on the fly) and serve only requests from single IP/id pair in a moment (not actually moment, but a predefined period) - if this condition failed, then black-list the compromised extension id. Of course, extensions ids should be checked against your DB. _PS. Do not forget to add @user in your replies.;-)_

Comment: @Stan your solution will work well if you host your extension or your own server but what if some extension has to be served from the Chrome Web Store? There is no way to alter the package once it is uploaded to you Chrome Web Store Account!

Comment: @fsenart Do you remember if you found any solution on this?

Comment: @Maleta, unfortunately, no viable solution. A real solution can only come from Chrome itself, and other solutions are at best 'security through obscurity'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sorry to say but this problem as posed by you is in essence unsolvable because of one simple problem: **You can't trust the client.** And since the client can see the code then you can't solve the problem.

Any information coming from the client side can be replicated by other means. It is essentially the same problem as trying to prove that when a user logs into their account it is actually the user not somebody else who found out or was given their username and password.

The internet security models are built around 2 parties trying to communicate without a third party being able to imitate one, modify or listen the conversation. Without hiding the source code of the extension the client becomes indistinguishable from the third party (A file among copies - no way to determine which is which).

If the source code is hidden it becomes a whole other story. Now the user or malicious party doesn't have access to the secrets the real client knows and all the regular security models apply. However it is doubtful that Chrome will allow hidden source code in extensions, because it would produce other security issues.

Some source code can be hidden using NPAPI Plugins as you stated, but it comes with a price as you already know.

---

Coming back to the current state of things:

Now it becomes a question of what is meant by interaction.

If interaction means that while the user is on the page you want to know if it is your extension or some other then the closest you can get is to list your page in the extensions manifest under *app* section as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#manifest)

This will allow you to ask on the page if the app is installed by using

```
    chrome.app.isInstalled
```

This will return boolean showing wether your app is installed or not. The command is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation#already-installed)

However this does not really solve the problem, since the extension may be installed, but not enabled and there is another extension mocking the communication with your site.

Furthermore the validation is on the client side so any function that uses that validation can be overwritten to ignore the result of this variable.

If however the interaction means making XMLHttpRequests then you are out of luck. Can't be done using current methods because of the visibility of source code as discussed above.

However if it is **limiting your sites usability to authorized entities** I suggest using regular means of authentication: having the user log in will allow you to create a session. This session will be propagated to all requests made by the extension so you are down to regular client log in trust issues like account sharing etc. These can of course be managed by making the user log in say via their Google account, which most are reluctant to share and further mitigated by blocking accounts that seem to be misused.

Comment: your solution will work only if the extension is served from the Chrome Web Store and does not work for extension served by your own server (you crx file on your server).

Comment: @fsehat my solution is not feasible even if you use the Crome Web Store, which was what I was trying to say. Here the question is what you call accessing the page. If by accessing you mean running some functions on your page then there is no possible solution without rewriting most of internet security models, because everything is on the client side. 

If we are talking about XMLHttpRequests then it would be more feasible- if chrome would implement automatically setting a header based on the extension making the request. But even so it doesn't stop anything else from sending the same thing.

Comment: @fsehat Updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do something similar to what Git utilises(have a look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects to understand how git implements it), i.e.

> **Creating SHA1 values of the content of every file in your
>   chrome-extension** and then re-create another SHA1 value of the
>   concatenated SHA1 values obtained earlier.

In this way, you can share the SHA1 value with your server and authenticate your extension, as the SHA1 value will change just in case any person, changes any of your file.

Explaining it in more detail with some pseudo code:

```
function get_authentication_key(){

    var files = get_all_files_in_extension,
        concatenated_sha_values = '',
        authentication_key;

    for(file in files){
        concatenated_sha_values += Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(get_file_content(file));
    }

    $.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/getauthkey',
  type: 'post'
  async: false,
  success:function(data){
         authentication_key = data;
  }
    })

    //You may return either SHA value of concatenated values or return the concatenated SHA values
    return authentication_key;  
}

// Server side code
get('/getauthkey') do
    // One can apply several type of encryption algos on the string passed, to make it unbreakable
authentication_key = Digest::<encryption>.hexdigest($_GET['string']);
return authentication_key;
end
```

This method allows you to check if any kind of file has been changed maybe an image file or a video file or any other file. Would be glad to know if this thing can be broken as well.

Comment: Wouldn't somebody would go to the trouble of imitating the behavior of an extension to match another's simply overwrite this function to return the expected value (obtained by running the function on the real extension) instead of the real hash?

Comment: Yep.. had thought of it, and the way you can overcome is to have a function defined on the server's side, that takes the concatenated hash string and applies another encryption algorithm over it and returns the Hash value.. in this way your part of the function to generate Hash doesn't get exposed to the guy wanting to break your code.

Comment: Here there are 2 problems: The main problem is you can't access the files to generate the hashes. 
Secondly the files are on the client side so if it came down to it then the client could simply send you the other files when you want to verify.
Plus having it on the server side would generate lots of unnecessary  network traffik @Cody

Comment: I am not asking you to send files on the network, instead just create the Hash of the JS files, bcoz that's the one that will be changing the logic, and about over the request to get back auth key, then it is a bit of burden, but it allows utmost level of protection.

Comment: Also, the result of this POST request can be cached. Haven't tried it myself, but will definitely check and get back on reading the file content of extension files.

Comment: Any verification/authentication process will require the client to hold some part of the secret or knowledge and as such it can be faked. Most authentication systems are built around the fact that the client also wants to preserve the secret not spread it.

If you don't send the files over the network then how do you know that the client even calculated the hash instead of sending a saved result? @Cody

Comment: one can try using obfuscators like Google Closure compiler to make the code hard to edit and use..

Comment: Firstly Google Closure compiler is not an obfuscator but a minifier. And any obfuscation and minification can be undone to a certain point with tools like http://jsbeautifier.org/ and others. Obfuscation is not really a solution, it's just a delay tactic. @Cody

Comment: @Cody imagine if somebody else take the exact hash that my extension sends to my server and sends it to my server from its extension to grant himself the access. As long as the hash is sent by a client code and not by an internal Chrome routine, it is copiable by anyone else.

Comment: I want to highlight the fact that Chrome does not provide any internal routine to permit a developer to authenticate its own extension in a way that is not copiable by a third party. We need something like `chrome.app.isAccessingThePage` but for both Chrome Web Store hosted applications and for own server hosted applications.