# How to securly identify browser-extension

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, restful-authentication

I have a `chrome extension` that talks to a server application via `REST` api (spring-based) .

I want to prevent others from talking to the REST api on the server.

Note, the extension itself is public, any one can use.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there is no bulletproof way to do it.

- Chrome extensions are client-side, and provided with an excellent debugger. Any sort of shared secret between your API and the extension is open for extraction from the running code.
- Chrome doesn't include any identifying headers to extension requests, but even if it did, it's possible to impersonate the extension by replicating the headers and/or hijacking the extension ID.

While you can make life difficult for people that try to emulate how your extension queries the API, ultimately it's not that hard to capture and replicate.

So, embrace the idea that you [cannot trust the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460297/how-to-check-the-authenticity-of-a-chrome-extension).

One way to approach this would be to require user accounts, and enforce quotas on those accounts. You *can* control account creation and privileges on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the link, do you think use a captcha will make hacking the backend harder?