# Allow requests only from my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a NodeJS server set up and working with Express, hosted on DigitalOcean. I'm making GET calls to it from within my Chrome extension. It currently works great, but I'd like to tighten down the security on the following middleware:

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); //todo: change this

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
});
```

The problem is, I think the `*` in `access-control-allow-origin` is letting anyone hit my endpoint. Is there a way to only allow calls from my Chrome extension, and not anywhere else?

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: do you want that your extension can make ajax call *only* to your servera and no other, or that only your extension can make calls to you server and no other extension can?

Comment: The latter - I want to be able to poll my server from my Chrome Extension, without the possibility of others hitting my server.

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: Pretty much duplicate of [How to check the authenticity of a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460297/how-to-check-the-authenticity-of-a-chrome-extension), but I'm not willing to swing my dupehammer.

Comment: @SamuelHill What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your extension will be installed on different computers with different IP addresses, there is no way to stop others from hitting your server. And certainly not with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, since it only works in a browser environment and in page context, not extension context, which is governed by different mechanism. Any application that can talk through HTTP will be able to reach your server. The only thing that you can do is to send some identification information through headers, and then you can verify on the server that the request is sent from your extension and process it. Otherwise, you can return `503 Service Unavailable` status code in your response. Of course, this solution can be worked around, by it implies knowing that your server does exist and knowing the IP address of it, and then also knowing the header and the value that should be sent.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! Should I use some kind of MD5 hash + salt to ensure no one can replicate the message?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. But if you want to provide higher security, you can create a routine with similar logic on both server and extension that will be generating some hash values on a daily or hourly basis. In this way, even if someone intercepts the valid headers value, it won't be accepted by the server for long