# How to securely send data from a website to extension

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, websecurity

## Context

We have a website with end-to-end-encrypted data. The user enters their master password on the login page and it is saved only in a variable locally on the client. Data is encrypted and decrypted on the fly.

Now we want to create an extension that allows an user to view their data. Because this data is e2e-encrypted, we need the user's master password. For convenience, the user should not be asked again for it in the popup, instead the website should send it to the extension securely.

## Problem

How do we securely send data from a website to the extension?

## Solutions

### Website saves the password in plaintext

1. The website saves the password in a `<script>` tag.
2. The extensions injects a content script.
3. This content script sends the password to the popup.

#### Problem

XSS attacks will lead to a leakage of the password.

### Website send passwords on events

1. The extension injects a content script.
2. This content script sends an event asking for the password.
3. The website listens to those events and sends back the password.

#### Problem

Again, an XSS attack will lead to the leakage of the password.

## Question

Is there any way to securely send data from the website to the extension? Can you verify the authenticity of the extension ([seems like you can not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460297/how-to-check-the-authenticity-of-a-chrome-extension))?

What's **currently** the most secure way to exchange sensitive data, such as passwords, between a website we control and an extension we control?

Comment: There's no such method because any code running in the web page (including another extension) can intercept the API to send messages, be it chrome.runtime.sendMessage or dispatchEvent. Maybe you can make a `fetch` request in your extension background script to your server using some unique id of the client, which is stored in chrome.storage.local.

Comment: Okay so basically it doesn't matter then what method I choose? I think I'd go with the second option then (via events), as it is the easiest one to implement. What do you think @wOxxOm

Comment: I guess. BTW you can prevent XSS attacks via CSP, but that may require a lot of work if you use unsafe js.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I found a good solution! So when the extension wants to get the password, it sends an event (via content scripts). Then, the website asks the user if they want to share the password. If the user is now confused, they will deny it, otherwise the password will be send via another event.